# How do i add a print button for a project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a button btnPrint on a form Form1 and I want the form to be printed when i click on btnPrint.

Comment: Erm, [Google?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629268.aspx)

Comment: Cheers man...i had that page open but couldn't take it in...blonde moment

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: what if there is no Visual Basic PowerPacks  tab in the toolbox...what do i do then?

Comment: Erm, [Google?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb735936.aspx) Seriously, dude, it ain't rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

Add PrintForm tool from ToolBox

In the print button ...

```
  Try
        PrintForm1.Form.AutoSize = True
        PrintForm1.Form.AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview
        PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.Scrollable)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```